# Binding to DataGrid ItemsSource in DataGrid ControlTemplate

Tags: c#, binding, silverlight-4.0, mvvm-light

Implementing a summary header row for a SL DataGrid I cannot find a way to bind to the DataGrids `ItemsSource` property (and apply an `IValueConverter`).

When simply specifying Binding the Converter receives the ViewModel as the DataGrids DataContext but I'd rather not couple the ViewModel to my Converter:

```
<!-- somewhere in my DataGrid ControlTemplate -->
<sdk:DataGridCell Content="{Binding Converter={StaticResource SummaryRow}}" />
```

I tried to create a `RelativeSource`, but xaml complains that I cannot use `AncestorType` in this context:

```
<sdk:DataGridCell Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Converter={StaticResource SummaryRow}}" />
```

My DataGrid itself is bound to a `CollectionViewSource` which handles grouping and sorting.

I already implemented displaying columns sums for `DataGridRowGroupHeader` using the first approach and the respective Converter receives a `CollectionViewGroup` from which I can retrieve items without coupling to the ViewModel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the correct way to achieve this and pass the `ListCollectionView` bound to the DataGrids `ItemsSource` to the `IValueConverter` inside my customized `ControlTemplate`:

```
<Style TargetType="sdk:DataGrid">
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="sdk:DataGrid">

    <!-- Rest of ControlTemplate xaml omitted -->

    <sdk:DataGridCell 
        Content="{Binding Path=ItemsSource, 
                          RelativeSource={RelativeSource}, 
                          Converter={StaticResource SummaryRow}}" />
    <!-- ... -->

    </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```